# Merge condition not working in oracle when trying to merge

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-update, sql-merge

I have a table as:

```
--------------
|id   descrip |
|1  A         |
|2  B         |
|3  C         |
|3  D         |
|3  E         |
|4  F         |
|4  F         |
```

My expected output is:

```
--------------
|id descrip |
|1  A       |
|2  B       |
|3C C       |
|3D D       |
|3E E       |
|4  F       |
|4  F       |
```

I tried using first method:

```
merge into rules_table a
using rules_table b
on (a.id = b.id and a.descrip and a.rowid > b.rowid)
when matched then
  update set a.id = b.id || b.descrip
```

The second method i tried is:

```
update rules_table a
   set a.id =
       (select b.id || b.descrip
          from rules_table b
         where b.id = a.id
           and b.descrip = a.descrip
           and a.rowid = b.rowid)
```

But,I am not getting desired output.

Comment: Ofcourse the result of the two statement will not be same. In `Merge` you havent specified the action when record is not matched

Comment: what is the solution then?

Comment: `a.id=b.id and a.descrip` this will always fail..!! Correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your expected result I think you are looking for the following:

```sql
MERGE INTO rules_table a
USING (SELECT rowid, id, descrip, COUNT(DISTINCT descrip) over (PARTITION BY id) cnt
         FROM rules_table) b
 ON (a.rowid = b.rowid AND b.cnt > 1)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
  SET a.id=b.id||b.descrip
```

Also the following should work:

```sql
UPDATE rules_table
   SET id = id||descrip
 WHERE id IN (SELECT id
                FROM rules_table
               GROUP BY id
              HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT descrip) > 1)
```

Comment: COLUMN REFRENCED IN THE ON CLAUES CANNOT BE UPDATED: "a"."ID"

Comment: I think as the same table is used you can use rowid instead, changed the answer accordingly.